# pkg-config cannot find any libraries without manual intervention

Tags: linux, libraries, pkg-config

I am not a C++ developer or typically work with Conan, CMake, or Makefiles. The first time I had heard of `pkg-config` was yesterday when conan started erroring on it, unable to resolve a `gl` package.

I managed to get it working with `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig"`.

Today, I tried to build `spotify_player` with `cargo` and it failed, unable to find the `alsa` library:

```
  --- stderr
  thread 'main' panicked at '`PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_SYSTEM_CFLAGS="1" PKG_CONFIG_ALLOW_SYSTEM_LIBS="1" "pkg-config" "--libs" "--cflags" "alsa"` did not exit successfully: exit status: 1
  error: could not find system library 'alsa' required by the 'alsa-sys' crate

  --- stderr
  Package alsa was not found in the pkg-config search path.
  Perhaps you should add the directory containing `alsa.pc'
  to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
  No package 'alsa' found
  ', /home/xevion/.cargo/registry/src/index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f/alsa-sys-0.3.1/build.rs:13:18
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

I looked around and found `alsa.pc` at `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/alsa.pc`. Exporting the variable in the exact same fashion as above fixes it.

That said, while it works - something is wrong. I was able to build and install `spotify_sound` in the exact same way as before a couple months ago. Nothing should have changed.

- I've reinstalled all associated libraries with `alsa`, as well as `pkg-config`.
- I'm working in a new terminal session.
- I've confirmed that `pkg-config` isn't finding it with `pkg-config --debug alsa`.
- Running Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS (Ubuntu 22.04) on a Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Carbon Gen 6.

`.pc` files can be found all over my computer - exporting in my `.bashrc` seems like a blockhead solution - something is happening on a greater level.

How do I fix `pkg-config` on my machine?

Comment: Is the version of `pkg-config` that is being invoked perhaps not what you think it is? what is the output of `type -a pkg-config`? and of `pkg-config --variable pc_path pkg-config`?

Comment: @steeldriver See here: https://gist.github.com/Xevion/20bde56e53e563e31772683e778dcd66 As for your question; I'm not sure what the effects of different versions of `pkg-config` would be. The tool is invoked by my build-tools, so I don't even know how it works beyond the basics.

Comment: OK so presumably you have `/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin` in your `PATH` ahead of the "system" locations `/bin`, `/usr/bin` - so you're getting the brew version of `pkg-config`, along with its built-in search path

Comment: Interesting. So my `pkg-config` search paths are currently resolving to whatever my brew installation has, which doesn't work well for the rest of my system, where `alsa.pc` would be resolved if I was using my `/usr/bin/pkg-config` version. It seems there are multiple ways of resolving this - rearranging `PATH` or trying to uninstall `pkg-config` from brew. I tried the second option, and brew wants to keep it for `pyenv` apparently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my solve for this wasn't particularly great. The issue was that my Linux Brew had `pkg-config` installed (for `pyenv`) and `pkg-config` resolved to it on my system (instead of the `apt` installed version).

This meant that any libraries I would have installed normally (`alsa` in this case) wouldn't be resolved as they weren't setup for Linux Brew's `pkg-config`.

Running

```
brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies pkg-config
```

uninstalled it (and `pyenv` isn't complaining yet).

A more ideal solution is in order, but I don't know enough about `PATH` manipulation or `pkg-config` itself to do so. If you have a better solution, create an answer and I may mark it as the answer for this question.